# Preform function inside ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can an AppDelegate run a "function" in a viewcontroller on receipt of a push notification?

The application contains three tabs, the third needs to reload its webview when the application gets a push notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you need to register your `viewController` for the particular notification, e.g  in your case when you receive a remote notification, just post a custom notification and in your viewController, register this notification/listen to this notification and perform the method you want to perform.

when you receive `remoteNotification`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

in your `viewController.m` register the viewcontroller for this notification

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushNotificationReceived) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

and next implement the selector

```
-(void)pushNotificationReceived{

// do your stuff

}
```

and finally don't forget to unregister from notification  in your `dealloc` method

```
-(void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```